# DAX: Measure % of itself

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot, dax

I am looking for help on creating a measure that is a % of itself or % of the column total. Currently I have to create a duplicate of the aggregate (customers) and then in format values --> Show as % of Column total. I would like to make the measure explicitly that %.

Example:

`State    |  Customers  |  New Measure
  GA      |     500     |    50%
  SC      |     250     |    25%
  NY      |     250     |    25%`

I would want this measure to update based on whatever filter or row column i use in my PowerPivot table.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression:

```
%cust = FORMAT((Sum(Tabla[Customers])/1000),"0%")
```

It will create a measure called `%cust` formatted to percent without decimals. If you want to get the decimals just replace `"0%"` by `"0.00%"`.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This didn't work exactly but thats because I didn't provide as much info as needed, but you did get me started and I found out this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Cust%:=Sum(table[cust])/CALCULATE(sum(table[cust]),ALL(table))

Answer (score 0):

This formula worked for me.

`Cust%:=Sum(table[cust])/CALCULATE(sum(table[cust]),ALL(table))`

Oh and I format the measure as a % since the value comes out as 1

Answer (score 0):

Define a sum measure -

```
[cust_msr]:
=sum(table[cust])
```

Define the % measure:

```
[Cust%:]=
divide(
[cust_msr]
,CALCULATE([cust_msr],ALL(table))
,blank())
```

Using divide is best practice as it means any error values are set to blank values. Of course, you can set them as 0 or -1 etc if you'd like.

Also, set the measure data type in the powerpivot window and you won't need to faff around with format()